# Vectorizing multidimensional cell arrays in matlab with colon

Tags: matlab, math

If I have a cell array that is:

```
example=cell(dim1,dim2,dim3);
```

I would like to access values in the shape of:

```
example1{:}{:}{1} = rand(20,1);
```

How can I do so? It is important to know that I would like to conserve the shape of such cell array, namely, to modify the values but having the same type of multidimensional cell array.

Comment: Why can't you use `example1{:,:,1}` which is the right way to index a 3d cell?

Comment: I tried to use example1{:,:,1} and it just returns: 
ans = 
    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}
ans = 
    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}
...

And I can even try example1{:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,1} and returns the same stuff.
Bare in mind that the dimensions I am using for the cell are aprox example1{10}{6}{3}{3}.

Comment: Something is wrong with the description in your question. Starting with `cell(dim1,dim2,dim3);´ you don't end up with that output. Please put the complete code required to create your data structure into the question.

Comment: Assuming we have `mymatrix = cell(10,6,3,3);`

If I do:
`mymatrix{:,1}`

Then I receive 10 times
`ans =
    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}`

And if I do:
`mymatrix{:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,:,1}`

I receive the same output, namely 10 times...
`ans =
    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}`

Comment: The example in your question has three dimensions, not four.

Comment: That was an example. So, which is the solution?

Comment: I am not sure what you expect to happen. Do you want to assign `[1 2 3, 1 2 3]` to each of the cells?

Comment: No, just to put a random array inside the cell. I'll edit it to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think now I understood your question.

```
mymatrix(:,:,:,1)=num2cell(rand(size(mymatrix(:,:,:,1))));
```

Easiest way to use `()` indexing which returns a cell, not a comma separated list of the individual elements. On the right side using `rand(size(x))` with the same indexing expressions makes sure you get the right amount of elements generated. The left side is a cell, so you have to convert the right side to a cell as well.

Comment: Namely that I cannot use vectorization with cells. I must convert the cells to matrixes, apply the formulas, and then convert them back to cells.

Comment: You can not vectorze operations on cell, that is right. When each element is the same you should use a matrix instead.